# Aggregate function problem

Tags: linq, aggregate

```
    List<MyClass> SampleList = new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass(), new MyClass(), new MyClass() };
    string AggCount = SampleList.Aggregate((counter, next) => counter.f_ToString() += next.f_ToString());
}

}

internal class MyClass
{
    public string f_ToString()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return rnd.Next(1000).ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: what is your question actually? the message is quite explicit actually: you cannot use the call to a method as something you want to assign

Comment: In addition to Luke's comment: **What are you actually trying to do?**

Comment: You should not instantiate the Random class every time you use it, you will get the same value if you call it too fast since the Random class instantiates it self with the current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a list of `MyClass` called `SampleList`, and for every item on it you want to call `f_ToString`, and create one string of them all. You don't really need `Aggregate`, try (on .Net 4.0):

```
string agg = String.Concat(SampleList.Select(myClass => myClass.f_ToString()));
```

On .Net 3.5 that Concat needs an array, so that would be:

```
string agg = String.Concat(
   SampleList.Select(myClass => myClass.f_ToString()).ToArray()
   );
```

If you still do want to use [Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspxhttp://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218.aspx), though there's no good reason here, it should be written as:

```
string agg = SampleList.Aggregate("", 
                     (counter, next) => counter + next.f_ToString());
```

Note that `counter` is a string here, so you can't call `f_ToString` on it.

As a final note, I'd warmly advise you to choose better names for your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You try to assign a value to the method f_ToString(). Replace **+=** with **+**

```
int AggCount = SampleList.Aggregate((counter, next) => counter.f_ToString() + next.f_ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

from

```
int AggCount = SampleList.Aggregate((counter, next) => counter.f_ToString() += next.f_ToString());
```

change to

```
int AggCount = SampleList.Aggregate((counter, next) => counter.f_ToString() + next.f_ToString());
```

becus u use assign operator instead of concat string

Comment: `int AggCount` should tip us off - the OP is probably trying to count something, and counter should probably be an `int`.